# Definition of principal ideal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

This is a pretty basic question about principal ideals - on page 197 of Katznelson's A (Terse) Introduction to Linear Algebra, it says:

> Assume that $\mathcal{R}$ has an identity element. For $g\in \mathcal{R}$, the set $I_g = \{ag:a\in\mathcal{R}\}$ is a left ideal in $\mathcal{R}$, and is clearly the smallest (left) ideal that contains $g$.
>
> Ideals of the form $I_g$ are called *principal left ideals*...

(Note $\mathcal{R}$ is a ring).

Why is the assumption that $\mathcal{R}$ has an identity element important?

Answer (score 5):

Because if $\mathcal{R}$ has an identity, then $I_{g}$ is the smallest left ideal containing $g$. Without an identity, it might be that $g \notin I_{g}$.

For instance if $\mathcal{R} = 2 \mathbf{Z}$, then $I_{2} =\{a \cdot 2:a\in 2 \mathbf{Z} \} = 4 \mathbf{Z}$ does not contain $2$.

(Thanks Cocopuffs for pointing out an earlier mistake.)

Answer (score 2):

Rings without identity (sometimes called rngs) do not behave as rings with identity (for instance, they may not contain maximal ideals), and many theorems that hold for rings with identity don't hold for rngs.

Comment: I thought a ring without i was a rong.

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ is a rng, the left ideal generated by an element $g$ (i.e. the smallest left ideal containing $g$) is given by the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of $\{g\} \cup \{rg : r \in R\}$. Thus, elements of $\langle g \rangle$ have the form $z \cdot g + r \cdot g$ for $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r \in R$.

Comment: sir, is principal ideal generated by $g$ always contains $g$? I know in case of commutative ring with unity, they does contains $g$ (because in this case $<g>=\{gr : r\in R\}$ and clearly for $r=1$ unity we have $g=g1$ and hence $g\in <g>$ ) But when $R$ is commutative ring "without unity" *then too* $g\in <g>$ just taking $z=1$ and $r=0\in R$ in your answer! ) So overall we see that in both cases $g\in <g>$. Am i correct? Please reply..